# Is it possible to return a String as an nginx error page from a reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx

I'm looking for a way to serve up a static message from nginx if an `upstreams` section returns certain HTTP codes. I understand that I could use static pages and ask NGINX to serve these up, but this is slightly more complicated that I need - all really need is (in pseudocode) to say

```
if($code_from_proxy_upstream == 500){
   return 500 'Error Occured'
}
```

I Read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/426347/nginx-reverse-proxy-error-page) question and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/196929/reply-with-200-from-nginx-config-without-serving-a-file#) question, but I don't think that they quite do what I need. I think that I need some combination of the two, but not quite sure of the syntax.

Comment: Not really. You can either have nginx pass through the errors from the backend, or serve a static document.

Comment: Your example is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pretty much got this to work.

I added a set of directives like this:

`error_page 508 @myerrordirective_508;`

and then

```
location @myerrordirective_508{
   return 508 "Error Occured"
}
```

The only pain was that nginx doesn't seem to allow me to use a variable to refer to the status (so that I could have just had one block with `$status` or whatever in it, which meant that each status needed an `error_page` and a `location` block.I therefore used a script to generate lines like the above for each error code, and put these into an include file which I linked from the main config

Seemed to do what I wanted.